# Finding newest columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read/parse some Excel-file through pandas dataframe into SQL Server.

The excel-file that I need to read is not completely static and column-names changes from time to time, but mostly in a fairly predictable manner - I am just not sure how to actually capture it. Also the order of the columns can change.

I need to find the column that holds the newest values/Amounts.

For example my Excel-file might look like this in one period:

```
| ID | Type | Amount May 20 | Amount Mar20   |
|----|------|---------------|----------------|
|  1 | red  |          1000 |            998 |
|  2 | blue |           400 |            400 |
```

Then perhaps the next Excel file looks like this:

```
| ID | Type | Amount May20  | Amount July 20 |
|----|------|---------------|----------------|
|  1 | red  |          1000 |           1050 |
|  2 | blue |           400 |            410 |
```

As you can see, sometimes the month is spelled out completely and a space between the month and the year, other times it could be spelled out in short format with only the first three letter directly followed by the year. It is arbitrary if there is a space between month and year or not - also it is arbitrary if the month is spelled out or not.

Also as you can see, the newest column is placed arbitrarily, some times the first amount is the newest, some times it is not (some files may hold several periods amount).

Any suggestions to how I can identify which column that holds the most recent value? i.e. in the first example it would be column 3 and in the second example it would be column 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might require a hack-y solution, given the inconsistencies. Import your Excel file and grab the column names, and then use string methods to pull out and track the relevant info. Luckily months are unique, and you can just use the abbreviation.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': np.random.randn(5),
                   'type': list('abcde'),
                   'Amount May 20': np.random.randint(1,5,5),
                   'Amount Mar20': np.random.randint(5,10,5)})
most_recent_yr = 19
recent_cols = []
for col_name in df.columns[2:]:
    col_yr = int(col_name[-2:])
    if col_yr >= most_recent_yr:
        recent_cols.append(col_name)
        most_recent_yr = col_yr

months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
max_month = 0
for i in range(len(months)):
    for col in recent_cols:
        if (months[i] in col) & (i > max_month):
            max_month = i
```

Comment: Will try to see if I can get your solution to work when I get back to work tomorrow

Comment: If you aren't comparing the new file to the old file, then you're going to have to have something like this. Following that, if the labels are inconsistent, it's going to require some hard-coding, like what I've shown w/ the month-check.

Comment: This seems to work for my purpose after some minor adjustments :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could compare it using `NumPy` to get the column number for changes.

Say, today you get the dataframe `df`. So, save this in a file as:

```
import numpy as np
prev = df.values
np.save('prev.npy', prev)
```

Now, after one month, you get new dataframe `new_df`. Then load the previously saved values and compare using:

```
import numpy as np
prev = np.load('prev.npy')
new = new_df.values
print(np.where((prev==new)==False)[1])
# Output: array([3], dtype=int64

# Now save this new dataframe 
np.save('prev.npy', new)
```

For the very first time, you have to run the 1st code snippet. And from then onwards, the 2nd code snippet will give you the column number for changes.

> Note: Provide your own location to store the values. Make sure you do
> not delete the location accidently.

Comment: Perhaps I forgot to mention, I only deal with one file at a time, once a month, so I don’t think it is feasible to compare what is different between the two datasets unfortunately.

Comment: Tried using your code above, however seemingly I get the "cells" where a value has changed. However the issue is I need to identify which columns, not values, have changed and which ones are the newest. All values are expected to change, and also ID numbers etc. are not static.

Comment: The above code gives the column number which has changed. Do you need the column name? And what if all the values have been changed along with column name?

Comment: The column structure is not always the same, and the columns in mind also changes names - sometimes the data have history (meaning they include more columns with values, but suffixed with e.g. Mar20, Feb20 etc.). Therefore just knowing which columns have changed doesnt work. The underlying value is expected to always change from period to period (e.g. sales in March is not expected to be the same as sales in Feb).

Answer (score 0):

Parsing manually-generated dates is hard!  Here is a simple approach that works for the examples in the original post.

- I converted the 'date' columns to pandas Period objects; now you can use the all of the pandas/Python date functionality.
- I also used a dictionary (not regex) to process month names.  This lets you accommodate unconventional abbreviations, typos, etc. over time.

```
def column_to_period(column):
    
    # remove 'amount'
    column = column.lower().replace('amount', '').strip()
    
    # update as needed (e.g., November shows up as `nvo`)
    months = {
        'jan':  1, 'feb':  2, 'mar':  3, 'apr':  4, 'may':  5, 'jun':  6,
        'jul':  7, 'aug':  8, 'sep':  9, 'oct': 10, 'nov': 11, 'dec': 12,}

    try:
        year = int(column[-2:]) + 2000
    except ValueError:
        year = None
    
    month = months.get(column[:3], None)
    
    try:
        period = pd.Period(year=year, month=month, freq='M')
    except ValueError:
        period = None
        
    return period
```

To test:

```
columns = ['Amount May 20', 'Amount Mar20', 'Amount May20', 'Amount July 20']

periods = pd.PeriodIndex(
    column_to_period(c)
    for c in columns
).sort_values()

periods
PeriodIndex(['2020-03', '2020-05', '2020-05', '2020-07'], 
dtype='period[M]', freq='M')
```

ORIG RESPONSE:
You could put the columns from each data frame into a set, and then perform set operations to see what changed:

```
s1 = set(df1.columns)
s2 = set(df2.columns)
s2 - s1
```

It looks hard to parse the column names (i.e, extract date).  You may be able to put the most common versions into a dictionary, to speed the conversion.

Comment: Nice little hack, will definitely use that for other things! But unfortunately the two excel files are being loaded in a different times, so it is not feasible to compare them

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, I ended up re-writing the accepted answer a bit to get to the following solution:

```
def find_newest_metrics(cols):

years = ['17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30']
months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']


cols_in_max_years = []
newest_col_in_max_year = []


#Find out which year is the most recent e.g. "OE May20" is newer than "OE Dec19"
max_year = 0
for i in range(len(years)):
    for col in cols:
        if (years[i] in col) & (i > max_year):
            max_year = i

#Find all the columns that have the most recent years, e.g. "OE May 20" and "OE Feb 20" will be kept, while "OE Dec 19" will be thrown away
for col in cols:
    if (years[max_year] in col):
        cols_in_max_years.append(col)

#If none of the columns contains one of the available years from 17-30, then continue with the original columns.
if len(cols_in_max_years) < 1:
    cols_in_max_years = cols

#Find out which month (in the list of columns that has the most recent year) is the most recent e.g. "OE May20" is newer than "OE Dec19"
#If the columns don't contain the year, then the whole original list is processsed; in that case the most recent available month will be treated as the newest
max_month = 0
for i in range(len(months)):
    for col in cols_in_max_years:
        if (months[i] in col) & (i > max_month):
            max_month = i

#Find all the columns that has the most recent month (in the list of columns that has the most recent year)    
for col in cols_in_max_years:
    if (months[max_month] in col):
        newest_col_in_max_year.append(col)

if len(newest_col_in_max_year) < 1:
    if len(cols) >= 1:
        return_val = cols[0]
    else:
        return_val = ""
else:
    return_val = newest_col_in_max_year[0]


return return_val
```